# 'springSecurityFilterChain' throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

When I run my project, I get a nullpointerexception.

I've pretty much looked at all stackoverflow posts relating to this sort of nullpointerexception due to 'springSecurityFilterChain' but cannot seem to fix this error.

Stack trace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-23 15:40:29.484 ERROR 17859 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.assignment.restapi.RestapiApplication.main(RestapiApplication.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:198) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:207) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoCustomConfiguration$SsoSecurityAdapter.invoke(OAuth2SsoCustomConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.assignment.restapi.web.FacebookController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$952d9225.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b7f48c2.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b7f48c2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$937dddf6.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b7f48c2.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

FacebookController:

```
package com.assignment.restapi.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.Principal;

@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class FacebookController extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
        @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(OAuth2Authentication oAuth) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oAuthDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) oAuth.getDetails();
            OAuth2AccessToken registeredToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(oAuthDetails.getTokenValue());
            if (registeredToken == null) {
                //上がnullなので新規トークンクラスの作成
                DefaultOAuth2AccessToken newToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(oAuthDetails.getTokenValue());
                //新しくトークンを入れる。facebookでログイン成功したらtokenvalueが飛ばされる。
                tokenStore.storeAccessToken(newToken, oAuth);
            }
            return oAuth;
    }
//    @RequestMapping("/user")
//    public String user(Principal principal) {
//        System.out.println("one");
//        if (principal == null) {
//            return "/accessWithoutLogin";
//        }
//        System.out.println("two");
////        return principal;
//        return "test";
//    }
    //    @RequestMapping("/user")
//    public String user() {
//        return "/accessWithoutLogin";
//    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/products**", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().deleteCookies().invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

RestapiApplication.java:

```
package com.assignment.restapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.Principal;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestapiApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestapiApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
}
```

AspectController.java:

```
package com.assignment.restapi.web;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Component
@Aspect
public class AspectController {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Before("within(com.assignment.restapi.web.*)")
    //何もなかったらスルーされる
    public void tokenCheck(JoinPoint jp) {
        HttpServletRequest request = this.findHttpRequest(jp.getArgs());
        if (request == null) {
            return;
        }
        String tokenValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(tokenValue)) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("no token");
        }
        //tokenstoreと照合
        OAuth2AccessToken registeredToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
        if (null == registeredToken) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("wrong token");
        }
    }
    private HttpServletRequest findHttpRequest(Object[] args) {
        for (Object arg:args) {
            if (arg instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                return (HttpServletRequest) arg;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.assignment</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>restapi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-cookie</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jquery</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.1.1</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>3.2.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the controller and the configuration in FacebookController.

```
@RestController
public class FacebookController {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
        @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(OAuth2Authentication oAuth) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oAuthDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) oAuth.getDetails();
            OAuth2AccessToken registeredToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(oAuthDetails.getTokenValue());
            if (registeredToken == null) {
                //上がnullなので新規トークンクラスの作成
                DefaultOAuth2AccessToken newToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(oAuthDetails.getTokenValue());
                //新しくトークンを入れる。facebookでログイン成功したらtokenvalueが飛ばされる。
                tokenStore.storeAccessToken(newToken, oAuth);
            }
            return oAuth;
    }

}


@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class FacebookConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/products**", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().deleteCookies().invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

I'm not completely sure if it solves your problem immediately but it's never a good idea to put configuration and controller/service methods into the same class.

Comment: Implemented your feedback and got a new error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used on com.assignment.restapi.RestapiApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a87a5a7@1c620974, so it cannot be used on com.assignment.restapi.web.FacebookConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$762d50fb@4bf

Comment: Are you sure you didn't annotated you main class with any other annotation? Or made it extend some configuration. The exception says that it's annotated with an Order(100) somehow...